# Ubuntu 12.04 boots to low-graphics mode with nvidia-173

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I have an older graphics card in a computer that were hoping to keep with Edubuntu 12.04 for the kids. Its a Nvidia Quadro PCI-E.
I know that I need nvidia-173 driver (mainly used the one provided by Ubuntu from the software centre) but then I just boot to the low-graphics.

I have then spent hours going through the posts here and on the ubuntu/support. From what I can tell by the `Xorg.0.log`, it's not compiling the nvidia module.

In my `dmesg.0` log there are the lines:

```
nvidia:module license 'NVIDIA taints kernel'

Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint

nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

nvidia: Unknown symbol acpi_os-wait_events-complete (err 0)
```

This question may be a duplicate of the many out there but I swear I have tried pretty much all the suggested solutions except for the more complicated ones (newbie). I was hoping that the detail in my logs would provide a more precise answer. My monitor is a Princeton. Once in a while I get screen hardware error (not Ubuntu but coming from the screen) "Out of Range". Could this also be the screen? Do I need to give up and shell out for a new old computer?

Answer (score 0):

This symbol is not exported in v3.13 and later. See [v3.12:osl.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.12/drivers/acpi/osl.c#L1179) and [this diff](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/63ff4d0765a4e30afa659edbf09006987fc62499#diff-4c8181dd2c9a8cae50adbb38faeffd53L1199) where the export was removed.

Luckily, right now, v3.12 is still supported, see http://kernel.org .

So simply read the latest v3.12 release number, search for it on [ubuntu mainline kernel releases](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/), and download the kernel and the headers (all and the i386/amd64).